# What do I do if my question has become too messy and chaotic?

Tags: discussion, questions

I posted a quite long and messy question. It now has half a dozen comments and a proposed solution, but while I kept looking for a solution I realized one of the two attempts of code I tried is wrong (so half of the text is obsolete, which I preemptively marked with an EDIT).

Also, I realised I could simplify my question so people stops looking at side problems instead of focusing on the problem I really need to solve.

So I don't know if I should delete the question and start anew, edit it radically or create a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're able to determine that significant portions of the question are actually irrelevant *to the question that you were asking* then you should *absolutely* remove that content. Doing so makes it much easier for people reading the question to understand it.

Likewise, if you feel that the wording of portions of your question is resulting in people misunderstanding what the question is asking you should *absolutely* be editing those portions of the question so that they are clearer, and so that readers will be more likely to understand what you're asking.

If, on the other hand, you simply realize now that the quesiton that you asked isn't going to help you solve your problem, and that the quesiton you wished you would have asked is something different, then it's not appropriate to edit the question into one that is *asking for something completely different* just because you're now more interested in the different question.  If this is the case then you simply need to ask a new question (and are free to leave the original question behind if there's a chance others might be interested in that question).

Comment: Then would you simply dismiss or remove portions of the question even if the answer provided, who has those parts into account, is helpful? I mean, the answer is not being completely misunderstood, but I could have explained it in a simpler way.

Comment: @Ika Yes, absolutely I would.  If someone misunderstands a question and posts an incorrect answer, the question is not obligated to conform to that answer's invalid interpretation.  If they (or someone else) feel that that information is useful, they can post that answer to a question actually asking the question it answers.